# Ошибка при установке библиотеки tensorflow в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, библиотеки, pip, tensorflow

Возникает ошибка при установке библиотеки tensorflow в PyCharm:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

версия PyCharm 2020.1.3
версия Python3 3.8.3

понятно что ругается на версию, но встает вопрос, а какая версия будет работать с tensorflow?

Comment: я бы не стал экспериментировать с python 3.8.x

Comment: C 3.8.3 проблем не должно быть, tensorflow его поддерживает, PyCharm скорее всего тоже не при делах. Если у вас виртуальное окружение - активируйте его в терминале, запустите `python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"` и скопируйте сюда результат, запустите `pip install tensorflow` - все таже ошибка?

Comment: да тоже самое

C:\Python3>python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"

3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)]

C:\Python3>pip install tensorflow

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: на последний `PyCharm 2020.2 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-202.6397.98, built on July 27, 2020`  + `Python 3.8.5` либа встала без каких либо замечаний. Так-что Pycharm и Python тут ни при чем думаю

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow установился на версию Python 3.6.6. Скорее всего установиться на 3.7.x, но на 3.8.x не устанавливается